# trying to combine columns from different excel files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

[image]ok i am trying to combine columns from different excel files. for example one file has address1,address2,city,state,zip and the other has location address, city,state,zip.
i appended the excel files, you can see from the code below that i combined the first set of columns with no problem. the problem is combining the second set of columns any tips are welcome. the picture below is the outcome im looking for

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files_xls:
  qw = pd.read_excel(f)
  df = df.append(qw)
  df = df.replace(np.nan,' ', regex=True)
  cf = df.iloc[:, df.columns.str.contains('address1|address2|city|state|zip|Location Address|City|State|ZIP', case=False)]
  vf= df['address1'].map(str) + '-' + df['address2'].map(str) + '-' + df['city'].map(str) + '-' + df['state'].map(str) + '-' + df['zip'].map(str),
  df['Location Address'].map(str) + '-' + df['City'].map(str) + '-' + df['State'].map(str) + '-' + df['ZIP'].map(str)
  export_csv = vf.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=None, header=True)
```

Comment: can you provide input and expected output as well?

Comment: [this blog](https://medium.com/ricoh-digital-services/mundane-excel-tasks-made-easy-with-pandas-python-part-i-797f6700d987) may help

Comment: i added a picture of the output. the input is just a excel file with the addresses in different columns.

Answer (score 0):

I added you second part in variable and create another DF and add both part to different DF and then write to csv file

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)

files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']
df = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files_xls:
    qw = pd.read_excel(f)
    df = df.append(qw)
    df = df.replace(np.nan,' ', regex=True)
    cf = df.iloc[:, df.columns.str.contains('address1|address2|city|state|zip|Location_Address|City|State|ZIP', case=False)]
    vf = df['address1'].map(str) + '-' + df['address2'].map(str) + '-' + df['city'].map(str) + '-' + df['state'].map(str) + '-' + df['zip'].map(str)
    vf1 = df['Location_Address'].map(str) + '-' + df['City'].map(str) + '-' + df['State'].map(str) + '-' + df['ZIP'].map(str)
    df1['part1'] = vf
    df1['part2'] = vf1
    export_csv = df1.to_csv('dataframe.csv', index=None, header=True)
```

output

```
part1,part2
300 DUFFERIN AVE - LL119- -london-OH-N6A 4L9,150 jimmy ave-md- -19977
301 DUFFERIN AVE - LL119- -london-OH-N6A 4L10,151 jimmy ave-md- -19978
302 DUFFERIN AVE - LL119- -london-OH-N6A 4L11,152 jimmy ave-md- -19979
303 DUFFERIN AVE - LL119- -london-OH-N6A 4L12,153 jimmy ave-md- -19980
```

Comment: thats my fault i did use vf, thats not the problem. the problem comes from reading the  second set with location address is shots a error.

Comment: KeyError: 'Location Address'
this only happens when i add the line df['Location Address'].map(str)+'-'+df['City'].map(str)+'-'+df['State'].map(str)+'-'+df['ZIP'].map(str) after the line were i combine the first set of columns.

Comment: I think I know the problem can you send me the excel files whatever you are using or just post the data on question, I'll take it from there

Comment: can you just explain the problem and i can do it on my end

Comment: i cant give you the data for security reasons

Comment: I understand you cant give me data but just send me one or two row as a test data or mock data

Comment: address 1=300 DUFFERIN AVE - LL119 , address2,city=london, state=OH          zip=N6A 4L9.     location address =150 jimmy ave, city=md,zip=19977. they are two serapate excel files in the same folder and whats left of the equal sign is the column name and to the right is what in the  cell.

Comment: good morning the code did not work. it shot back an error Keyerror:'  location address'

Comment: make sure Location_Address is same across everywhere

Comment: i did still did not work. did it work when you did it ??

Comment: I changed the code please feel free to try it will definitely works, if you still face any issue comment it here.

Comment: did you make two different excel workbooks with the sample data i gave you

Comment: I created one excel file with two column part 1 and part 2

Comment: thats the output correct or you only read one excel file as the input

Comment: Yes that’s output file. And I am reding data from multiple files

Comment: ok thank you i ran the code and its giving me the same error  key error 'Location Address'

Comment: is there way to share your screen and we do live session

Comment: we can use zoom

Comment: sure than lets do it share your ID

Comment: 744-370-2963 is my id

Comment: waiting for you to jin